# wordpress naked domain vs www

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, cpanel

I have a wordpress website `somewebsite.com`

If I visit it naked like that, it works brilliantly, however if I visit it from `www.somewebsite.com` I get

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/somewebsite/public_html/index.php:2) in /home/somewebsite/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1121
```

In the wordpress website general settings it's set to `somewebsite.com`

and in `CPANEL` I have the following

1. an `A record` with `somewebsite.com` pointing to the ip address
2. a `CNAME record` with `www.somewebsite.com` pointing to `somewebsite.com`

Just for kicks I changed the setting in the wordpress general settings to `www.somewebsite.com` which fixed it for if I was to visit it with the `www` but broke it for the naked domain, so I switched it back.

my `.htaccess` looks like

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple is best :-) Redirect non-www to www or www to non-www using .htaccess, so user is going to be redirected before loading any script in php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

In your example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Remember to change chmod for .htaccess - it can be overwritten by WordPress in some cases.